# Extend element on side of screen to bottom of screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making an angular web-app with a sidebar view attached to the side of every page. I'm using twitter-bootstrap to handle grid/spacing on the page and ui-router to handle the different views.

My views are laid out like this:

index.html

```
<div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
<div ui-view="content-2"></div>
```

The markup for my sidebar is as follows:

sidebar.html

```
<div class="col-sm-3 sidebar">
  <!-- sidebar view content -->
</div>
```

and the markup for my content views:

content.html and content-2.html

```
<div class="col-sm-9 container-fluid">
  <!-- content view content -->
</div>
```

the content views are stacked one on top of the other next to my sidebar.

The problem is that one of my pages includes a dynamically expanding component, which increases the height of the content views. This pushes the lower content view ('content-2') down the page, and when it goes below the bottom of the sidebar view, it slides left, underneath the sidebar, instead of staying on the right below the first content view.

I've tried adding `style="padding-bottom:500px"` and `style="vh:100"` to the sidebar div, which works for a bit because it extends that view down, but I'd prefer a solution that doesn't unnecessarily extend the page beyond what is currently necessary. Additionally, once the content-view2 reaches the bottom of the padding, it still slides over just like before.

---

### Update:

I finally got my plunker up, so hopefully this will illustrate the problem and what I'm trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/EbGJAqxdjHRCMjjC6waA

The content.html view will dynamically increase/decrease when the user presses the button, illustrating the problem (make sure to scroll down to see what I'm talking about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest working solution without layout changes. The problem is the float:left of the 2nd content, so let's change it to right when the screen size is large enough - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bLxPCYMfhdAkDsqNb5bL?p=preview):

```
<div class="content2 col-md-10 container-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background:#800000;color:white">
    <h2>Content Frame Two</h2>
    <p>Centered below Frame One at start, should still be centered after button press.</p>
  </div>
</div>

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .content2 {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

A simpler working solution + [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2fmguhW4wCZnr4PyXAsq?p=preview):

Remove this from sidebar - `style="padding-bottom:100vh"` - as we don't need it anymore.

Change your html markup, so that both content areas would be wrapped in one big float. In this way, the 2nd content, can slide left.

Index:

```
<div class="container">
  <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10 container-fluid">
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    <div ui-view="content-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Content 1:

```
<div class="col-md-12 container-fluid" style="padding-bottom:20px">
  <!-- the padding on the following container is to simulate the added space 
  that appears once the div dynamically increases in size -->
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-style="vm.contentStyle">
    <h2>Content Frame One</h2>
    <button ng-click="vm.expand()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">{{ vm.change }} Size</button>
    <p ng-show="vm.info">{{ vm.info }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Content 2:

```
<div class="col-md-12 container-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background:#800000;color:white">
    <h2>Content Frame Two</h2>
    <p>Centered below Frame One at start, should still be centered after button press.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Previous non-working solution:

It's bit hard to hard to replicate the problem without a working plunker/fiddler, but I think that setting the height of the sidebar to 100vh or the padding to `calc(100vh - height of sidebar)` will solve your problem.
1vh is 1% of the view port height - ie the available browser display area, so setting it using vh will resize your sidebar or the padding dynamically according to screen height.
Note of caution - vh (and vw) are only supported by modern browsers (see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)).

Comment: Actually looking at it now, this just seems to extend the distance I can add the dynamic elements before it slides over again :( not sure why it does that, maybe it just calculates the viewport height when the page initially loads up?

Edit: Yeah I think it's 100% of the height of the initial containing block. So while this is good because it doesn't increase beyond the initial bounds, it also doesn't update dynamically.

Comment: Try padding-bottom: 100vh.

Comment: That doesn't work after a point either, and it has the same problem of adding unnecessary space to the screen. I've updated my main question to include a plunker, so hopefully this can help you or someone else!

Comment: I've edited the plunker to include solution + changes appear here.

Comment: This works. And for most people's purposes will work. But is there a way to do this without putting the bootstrap col tags in index.html? All of my bootstrap spacing is dynamically updated based on what state the user is in (i.e. those two content views are side-by-side login/signup views in another state, *not* on top of each other). Is there a way to float them without using the bootstrap .col tags?

Comment: What browsers are you targeting?

Comment: Just chrome, firefox, and edge, all the latest stuff.

Comment: With a little bit of tweaking, I got that to work. Thank you so much for sticking with me and sorry it took me so long to get out a working plunker!

Comment: Welcome, and thank you - it was an interesting and knowledge rewarding challenge.